# How do I access context key values in vscode extension?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

#### Description

I am setting a `configPath` context variable using...

```
const configPath = '/some/file/path.yml';
vscode.commands.executeCommand(
  'setContext',
  'ext.configPath',
  configPath
);
```

... which can be used within `when` properties in `package.json`. For example, `"when": "ext.configPath"`.

#### Problem

I cannot seem to obtain the value for string interpolation, or programmatically.

#### Ask

I would like to know...

1. How to interpolate the context variable value within a string in the package.json file. For example, for tree data title...

```
{
  "id": "ext.treedata.accounts",
  "name": "Accounts - ${context:ext.configPath}",
  "when": "ext.configPath"
}
```

... I would expect the title to read `Accounts - /some/file/path.yml`.

2. How to obtain the context variable value programmatically. For example...

```
const configPath = vscode.getContext('ext.configPath');
console.log(configPath); // Outputs: /some/file/path.yml
```

I've tried using ${context:ext.configPath} to interpolate, and I've tried looking for `getContext` methods. I've also tried searching the vscode extension development docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getContext` API/command, unfortunately. There is however, an open issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10471), but no ETA.

So, in your case, you will have to store that value somewhere. Depending on your scenarios, maybe you could take advantage of `workspaceState` or `globalState` Mementos.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I posted in the open issue to request the ability to interpolate a context variable value also -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10471#issuecomment-1318797088