# "when clause contexts" in extension code problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to fix https://github.com/LukeGeneva/vscode-auto-collapse-explorer extension.
The problem is it's triggers when explorer tab isn't active, and this causes git or search tabs to loose focus.
Possible fix would be check if explorer is open.

I found bunch of ui contexts, in particular `explorerViewletVisible`. But I don't understand how to use it in code.

Comment: is it triggered by a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74467401/9938317